# Setting cron for boto-rsync

Tags: cron, boto

I am trying to run `boto-rsync` 
using `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `date`
echo "start"
boto-rsync -d 2 -a <access key> -s <secure key>  s3://db-dump/hourly/2013/ /mnt/dir
echo "stop"
```

It works perfectly fine.
But when I run this using `crontab`, it ignores `boto-rsync` line.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this.
We need to add python and location of file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `date`
echo "start"
python <location of boto-rsync> -d 2 -a <access key> -s <secure key>  s3://db-   dump/hourly/2013/ /mnt/dir
echo "stop"
```

Answer (score 1):

Nine times out of ten, when you have a problem where something runs fine until you put it into  a cron script, the underlying issue is that the cron script is running as a different user (root, usually) and the environment is not set up to access the command in question.  So try doing a "su" and then typing "boto-rsync" and see if it's able to find the command.